# Sanitize $PATH for find -execdir

Tags: bash, path, find, relative-path, sanitization

`find -execdir` is recommended over `-exec`, which the manual says has unavoidable security issues, and lists in the [bugs](https://manned.org/find#head14) section.

`man find` says regarding `-execdir`:

> If you use this option, you must ensure  that  your
>                 `$PATH`  environment  variable  does  not  reference  `.`;  otherwise, an
>                 attacker can run any commands they like by  leaving  an  appropriately-
>                 named  file  in  a  directory in which you will run `-execdir`.  The same
>                 applies to having entries in `$PATH` which are empty  or  which  are  not
>                 absolute  directory names.

In a `bash` script, how does one comply with the manual's "must" and remove all relative or empty elements from `$PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sanitize your `PATH` using the following bash function:

```
sanitize_PATH()
{
    local new_path=""
    local dir
    while read -r -d: dir
    do
        if [[ $dir == /* ]]
        then
            new_path="$new_path:$dir"
        else
            echo "dropping from PATH: '$dir'"
        fi
    done <<< "$PATH:"
    PATH="${new_path#:}"
    echo PATH="$PATH"
}
```

Testing:

```
$ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin       sanitize_PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

$ PATH=:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin      sanitize_PATH
dropping from PATH: ''
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

$ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:      sanitize_PATH
dropping from PATH: ''
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

$ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:      sanitize_PATH
dropping from PATH: ''
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

$ PATH=.:bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin sanitize_PATH
dropping from PATH: '.'
dropping from PATH: 'bin'
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

$ PATH=/usr/local/bin::/usr/bin:/bin      sanitize_PATH
dropping from PATH: ''
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```